# Масштабирование изображения

Tags: javascript, изображения, graphics

Пишу программку с помощью js для масштабирования изображения. Оговаривались след. требования:

- масштабирование вокруг точки-центра
- некое пропорциональное масштабирование (не могу сформулировать точнее)

Как шаги для работы было намечено следующее:

1. получить координату точки, по которой щелкает мышь
2. получить площадь фигуры под этой точкой
3. расширить изображение в каких-то пропорциях (функция от координаты точки, площади фигуры, параметров масштабирования)
4. говорилось что-то об использовании алгоритма flood fill для масштабирования (как возможном варианте для данной задачи - может, он является неверным)

Может ли кто-нибудь дать более подробные пошаговые инструкции-алгоритм с пояснением того, что требуется в таком абстрактном задании? И некие наводки на технологии для этого всего.

Пока что я лишь знакомилась с canvas и svg графикой, читала про алгоритм flood fill.

Буду очень благодарна за помощь в разборе такой "каши" (в голове).

Comment: Вот видите что бывает когда вопросы не задаешь когда задание получаешь. Так что масштабировать все изображение или только выделенную часть?

Comment: Да, это я уже поняла. Но и когда ты новичок, тоже сложно сходу задать нужные вопросы.. Все изображение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял так:

1. Определяете точку в которую щелкнул пользователь.
2. С помощью алгоритма [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) находите набор точек, то есть определяете фигуру на которую щелкнул пользователь.
3. Как-то (вы сами так написали) масштабируете эту фигуру относительно либо точки центра, либо точки по которой щелкнул пользователь.

Я все ж таки рекомендую подробно расспросить того кто вам давал задание, засунув стеснение и гордость в укромные места.

Comment: Оказалось задача состояла в том, чтобы распознавать элементарные фигуры на картинке, так называемая проблема blob detection, и по выбору пользователя увеличивать какую-то из них в размере. Теперь уже буду думать о том, какие алгоритмы использовать для реализации.